# Op-Amp Design Resistor Values vs. Actual Values - Gain Calculation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

I have created the following differential op-amp circuit with the aim of converting a 0-3.28V analog signal into a -10V to +10V output. I have calculated the gain required 3.28/20 = 6.1

From looking at differential circuits the gain is equal to the ratio of resistors used so I chose a 10k and 61k. However when testing the circuit I needed close to 74k to get the required output range. Can anyone explain why there is such a difference between the design values and the actual resistor values?

[image]

PS. The voltage divider in the top left is to provide the midpoint value 1.64V for the circuit.

---

This should really be added as a comment but need to add the link. I found a formula on the following website, maybe I misinterpreted it.

http://cnx.org/content/m13778/latest/

[image]

Clearly this is not the case, thank you for your explanation, it is by far the easiest to understand that I have seen so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look at the *signal* gain from the non-inverting terminal (setting the rheostats to 0)

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_+} = 1 + \dfrac{69k}{10k+1.91k||10k} = 6.95$$

The voltage at the non-inverting terminal is

$$V_+ = V_2 \dfrac{69k}{10k + 69k} =  V_2 \cdot 0.873$$

The overall signal gain is thus

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_2} = 6.95 \cdot 0.873 = 6.07$$

Which is very close to the desired value.  How did you arrive at the conclusion that 61k and 10k should give the correct gain?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems:

1. The voltage divider you say is generating a 1.64V reference will be affected by the output current of the op-amp.  You may need to buffer the 1.64V before the second 10k\$\Omega\$ resistor.
2. Another possible problem (though I don't think it's quite as likely), is that the op-amp gain is reduced when the output is near the supply rails. Check your op-amp datasheet.  As an example, here is a line from the datasheet of a random rail-to-rail op-amp I found, the AD8565 (looks like it's designed for single supply operation, but the principle is the same):
   [image: Large Signal Voltage Gain | Vo=0.5V to (Vs-0.5V)]
   You can check if this is the problem by cutting the DAC output voltage in half and seeing if the gain is more accurate.